# Puppeteer node_modules TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'formatters' of 'module.exports' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, testing, typeerror, node-modules, puppeteer

I am trying to use puppeteer, and it seems it is setup alright as this passes :

setup.spec.js

```
    it('should define page', async () => {
        await expect(page).not.toBeNull()
    });
})
```

but when I try to run this:

```
describe('Cleaning nav', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/cleaningtasks')
})

it('Renders correctly', async () => {
    await expect(page.title()).resolves.toMatch('Cleaning Tasks')
})})
```

I get this error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'formatters' of 'module.exports' as it is undefined.

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/debug/src/node.js:238:8)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/debug/src/index.js:9:19)
```

Found the issue!

It was because my config file had automock and clearMocks, it should only have "preset": "jest-puppeteer"

```
{
  "preset": "jest-puppeteer"
  "automock": true,
  "clearMocks": true
}
```

NOTE: Be sure to remove any existing testEnvironment option from your Jest configuration. The jest-puppeteer preset needs to manage that option itself.

Comment: are you using `jest-puppeteer` or jest? https://jestjs.io/docs/en/puppeteer

Comment: I'm using jest-puppeteer

Comment: 1) you don't need to define `browser` or `page` as they're automatically exposed in tests. (see example at https://jestjs.io/docs/en/puppeteer) 
2) `const`'s scope is at a block level, so if you define it in `beforeEach`, you won't be able to access it in `it`.